# Lock rows based on a Macro selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with columns A to I to be filled out with data. At the end of row in the G column I have added a macro so that i get a confirm dialog box of 'YES' & 'NO'. I have also added a macro so as when when you confirm, it locks the entire row. But the issue is when i click 'NO', it still locks the row. how can i change the code so i can unlock the entire row when i click 'NO'

Comment: Please post your code. It sounds like what you're missing is an `If` statement to handle the return value of your message box.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.